# How to verify if Tab on Web Page is selected using Selenium RC..?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

How to verify if Tab on Web Page is selected using Selenium RC

I wanted to one very simple thing. Does anyone know using selenium RC Python Client how I can know if a Tab is selected on web page?
By tab I mean the following examples from the following link-

http://esdi.excelsystems.com/wsexmp/DIVTAB.pgm?wsnum=00096

I have used focus(), isSomethingSelected(), isVisible() but didn't get the solution.
I need to verify that the specific tab is selected by default after webpage opens. Isn't there a method like is_tab_selected(tab_locator)??

please provide the clear solution pls..

Comment: Can you check the HTML property of the tab if there is any attribute is getting change after tab selected, or you can verify with the text on the page if "Pane 1 Content" is displayed it means Pane1 is selected.

Comment: Yes he can. The class attribute of the tab changes when clicked. So all he needs to do is verify that the attribute has changed.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...Can u give some example code please.. i can't able to find that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used `focus()`, `isSomethingSelected()`, `isVisible()` but didn't get
>   the solution.

These methods use the common HTML element terminology.

`focus()` is for elements that are focused, meant as when you click a focusable element, it has a focus on it. To see what I mean, you can loop through the focusable elements on your page via pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key repeatedly. This changes focus.

`is_something_selected()` is for selecatble `<option>` elements (which are the children of a `<select>` element)

`is_visible()` tells you whether an element is actually visible on the page or whether it is hidden via CSS.

---

Anyway, there's no `is_tab_selected(tab_locator)` method, because there's no such thing as a tab. In your case, your "tabs" are just simple clickable `<a>` elements which have a `class` attribute `tab-active` or `tab-disabled` based on their state.

Therefore, if you wanted, for example, to know whether the second tab is active, you would do

```
is_element_present("css=#tab2.tab-active")
```

This will return either true or false based on whether the tab is selected or not.

Or the other way around, if you wanted to know which tab is currently active, you would do:

```
get_attribute("css=.tab-active@id")
```

This will return the `id` of the selected tab.

Comment: Also note that Selenium RC has been deprecated two years ago and has not been developed since. If you can, switch to Selenium WebDriver which is newer, stronger, more stable and actively developed.

Comment: Hi Slanec, I have tried both the code is_element_present("css=#tab2.tab-active") but its getting true for all tabs. Then i tried "get_attribute("css=.tab-active@id")" but its showing error "Element.tab-active" was not found. can u pls help on this

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a unique tag in your webpage. You can do

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tagname"))
```

If the above line doesn't throw any exception, you can confirm that you are located in your webpage.